# textarea with a few editing options

Tags: javascript, html, text-editor

I need a simple text editor on my site, just with the following options:
- ordered and unordered lists
- heading or bold characters
- horizontal rule

Is there any way to get the above by coding, inside an existing `textarea` tag

I tried with `contentEditable` div but there is a lot of problems there, for example `return` changes the format of preceding text and so on.

Comment: A content editable is the way to go, `textarea` element contains only plain text, it can't have HTML. When using a content editable `div`, or maybe rather `<pre>`, you've to capture some key hits, e.g. TAB and ENTER, and prevent the default action.

Comment: If you want to stick with pure `textarea`, there are no formatting options available and you have to work with `key**` or `input` events only to create basically some basic kind of markup. But markup is the only way for `textarea` - heading won't be bigger or bolder, horizontal rule will be just dashes across the textarea, unordered list items will start with `*` or `-`, no clickable links etc. You can hardcode `contentEditable` to your needs, like change Enter key behavior. It's more work, but it's worth it.

Answer (score 8):

You can use ckeditor, it's very simple and customizable

https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/

Example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CKEditor 5 – Classic editor</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/11.0.1/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Classic editor</h1>
    <textarea name="content" id="editor">
        &lt;p&gt;This is some sample content.&lt;/p&gt;
    </textarea>
    <script>
        ClassicEditor
            .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
            .catch( error => {
                console.error( error );
            } );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/examples/textarea). It's a customizable wysiwyg editor, that can be configured to only have the features you asked for.